# Neural network specified with tf.layers inserting undesired reshape operations

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, snpe

This simple neural network defined in python:

```
input_layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 1, 8000, 1], name='input_layer')

# Convolutional Layer
conv = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=input_layer,
        filters=32,
        kernel_size=[1,11],
        padding="same",
        strides=1,
        activation=tf.nn.relu)

# Output layer
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=conv, units=5, name='logit')
```

Results the following graph topology:

```
0 input_layer Placeholder
1 conv2d/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape Const
2 conv2d/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min Const
3 conv2d/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/max Const
4 conv2d/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform RandomUniform
└─── Input0 ─ conv2d/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape
5 conv2d/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/sub Sub
└─── Input0 ─ conv2d/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/max
└─── Input1 ─ conv2d/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min
6 conv2d/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/mul Mul
└─── Input0 ─ conv2d/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform
└─── Input1 ─ conv2d/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/sub
7 conv2d/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform Add
└─── Input0 ─ conv2d/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/mul
└─── Input1 ─ conv2d/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min
8 conv2d/kernel VariableV2
9 conv2d/kernel/Assign Assign
└─── Input0 ─ conv2d/kernel
└─── Input1 ─ conv2d/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform
10 conv2d/kernel/read Identity
└─── Input0 ─ conv2d/kernel
11 conv2d/bias/Initializer/zeros Const
12 conv2d/bias VariableV2
13 conv2d/bias/Assign Assign
└─── Input0 ─ conv2d/bias
└─── Input1 ─ conv2d/bias/Initializer/zeros
14 conv2d/bias/read Identity
└─── Input0 ─ conv2d/bias
15 conv2d/convolution/Shape Const
16 conv2d/convolution/dilation_rate Const
17 conv2d/convolution Conv2D
└─── Input0 ─ input_layer
└─── Input1 ─ conv2d/kernel/read
18 conv2d/BiasAdd BiasAdd
└─── Input0 ─ conv2d/convolution
└─── Input1 ─ conv2d/bias/read
19 conv2d/Relu Relu
└─── Input0 ─ conv2d/BiasAdd
20 logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape Const
21 logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min Const
22 logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/max Const
23 logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform RandomUniform
└─── Input0 ─ logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape
24 logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/sub Sub
└─── Input0 ─ logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/max
└─── Input1 ─ logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min
25 logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/mul Mul
└─── Input0 ─ logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform
└─── Input1 ─ logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/sub
26 logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform Add
└─── Input0 ─ logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/mul
└─── Input1 ─ logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min
27 logit/kernel VariableV2
28 logit/kernel/Assign Assign
└─── Input0 ─ logit/kernel
└─── Input1 ─ logit/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform
29 logit/kernel/read Identity
└─── Input0 ─ logit/kernel
30 logit/bias/Initializer/zeros Const
31 logit/bias VariableV2
32 logit/bias/Assign Assign
└─── Input0 ─ logit/bias
└─── Input1 ─ logit/bias/Initializer/zeros
33 logit/bias/read Identity
└─── Input0 ─ logit/bias
34 logit/Tensordot/transpose/perm Const
35 logit/Tensordot/transpose Transpose
└─── Input0 ─ conv2d/Relu
└─── Input1 ─ logit/Tensordot/transpose/perm
36 logit/Tensordot/Reshape/shape Const
37 logit/Tensordot/Reshape Reshape
└─── Input0 ─ logit/Tensordot/transpose
└─── Input1 ─ logit/Tensordot/Reshape/shape
38 logit/Tensordot/transpose_1/perm Const
39 logit/Tensordot/transpose_1 Transpose
└─── Input0 ─ logit/kernel/read
└─── Input1 ─ logit/Tensordot/transpose_1/perm
40 logit/Tensordot/Reshape_1/shape Const
41 logit/Tensordot/Reshape_1 Reshape
└─── Input0 ─ logit/Tensordot/transpose_1
└─── Input1 ─ logit/Tensordot/Reshape_1/shape
42 logit/Tensordot/MatMul MatMul
└─── Input0 ─ logit/Tensordot/Reshape
└─── Input1 ─ logit/Tensordot/Reshape_1
43 logit/Tensordot/shape Const
44 logit/Tensordot Reshape
└─── Input0 ─ logit/Tensordot/MatMul
└─── Input1 ─ logit/Tensordot/shape
45 logit/BiasAdd BiasAdd
└─── Input0 ─ logit/Tensordot
└─── Input1 ─ logit/bias/read
```

What is the purpose of the reshape operations between nodes 36 and 44? I am working with the Snapdragon Neural Processing Engine (SNPE) which does not permit reshape operations. Is there any way to express this model without the reshape ops?

Comment: SNPE supports `reshape` in **v1.8.0**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these `reshape` ops are added by [`tf.tensordot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot), which is used by [`tf.layers.dense`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense) for high-dimensional inputs (in your case 4D). From its [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense):

> Note: if the inputs tensor has a rank greater than 2, then it is
>   flattened prior to the initial matrix multiply by kernel.

[The link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py#L150) to the source code.

If reshaping is undesired in your environment, try to define the weights and biases manually and apply the `dot` product via `tf.matmul`.

Comment: is there a way to do this without operations like Squeeze?

Answer (score 1):

SNPE supports `reshape` in **v1.8.0**